# Sailsjs MVC map params from external API to multiple models

Tags: mysql, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js, waterline

I need to create a database of shopify orders so I can run advanced queries and sales reports that you can't do in the shopify admin area. I'm building in Sails .12 and mysql. Shopify lets you register a webhook so that every time an order is placed, it creates a POST to the specified URL with the order data in the body as JSON. The products ordered are an array of JSON objects as one of the values in the POST:

```
{
  "id": 123456,
  "email": "jon@doe.ca",
  "created_at": "2017-01-10T14:26:25-05:00",
...//many more entires
  "line_items": [
    {
        "id": 24361829895,
        "variant_id": 12345,
        "title": "T-Shirt",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": "140.00",
    },
    {
        "id": 44361829895,
        "variant_id": 42345,
        "title": "Hat",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": "40.00",
    },
  ]
}
```

I need to save the order into an Orders table, and the products ordered into a line_items table that is a one to many relation; one order can have many line_items (products ordered). There are over 100 key-value pairs sent by the webhook, and I'm saving all of it. I've created my two models where I define the data type, so now i have very long Order.js and Line_item.js files, and I'm using the

```
    line_items: {
    collection: 'line_item',
    via: 'order_id'
},
```

in my Order.js, and

```
order_id: {
    model: 'order'
},
```

in my Line_item.js models to relate them. Is this the correct way to denfine my two tables? Also, where would I put the code that maps the JSON to the model parameters? If I put that code in the controllers, would I have to type another 100+ lines of code to map each json value to its correct parameter. The how would I save to the two different models/tables? Eg:

```
    var newOrder = {};
    newOrder.id =req.param('id');
    newOrder.email = req.param('email');
    newOrder.name = req.param('name');
    ...//over 100 lines more, then Order.create(newOrder, ...)

    var newLine_items = req.params('line_items'); //an array
    _.forEach(newLine_items, function(line_item){
        var newLine_item = {};
        newLine_item.id = line_item.id;
        newLine_item.order_id = newOrder.id;
        newLine_item.title = line_item.title;
        //etc for over 20 more lines, then Line_item.create(newLine_item, ...)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I need to save the order into an Orders table, and the products ordered into a line_items table that is a one to many relation; one order can have many line_items (products ordered).`

That sounds completely reasonable, well, besides the use of the Oxford comma :)

`There are over 100 key-value pairs sent by the webhook`

I'm not sure that I understand exactly what this is or what it is used for within this process.

That being said, it might help to have a single attribute in your model for this which has a JSON value, then retrieve and work with it as JSON instead of trying to manually account for each attribute if that is what you're doing over there?

It really depends on your use case and how you'll use the data though but I figure if the format changes you might have a problem, not so if it's just being stored and parsed as a JSON object?

`Also, where would I put the code that maps the JSON to the model parameters`

In v0.12.x take a look at [Services](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/services).

In v1, Services will still work but moving this logic into [Helpers](http://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers) might be a good option but then, it seems that a [custom model method](http://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models#?custom-model-methods) would be a better one.

Here is a shorter version of your code:

```
var newOrder = req.allParams();
newLine_items = {};
_.forEach(newOrder.line_items, function(line_item) {
    newLine_items.push(line_item);
});
```

Here is what your logic might look like:

```
var newOrder = req.allParams();

// Store the order
Order
.create(newOrders)
.exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) // handle the error

    var newLine_items = {};

    _.forEach(newOrder.line_items, function(line_item) {
        // Add the order id for association
        line_item.order_id = result.id;
        // Add the new line item with the orders id
        newLine_items.push(line_item);
    });

    // Store the orders line items
    LineItems
    .create(newLine_items)
    .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) // handle the error

        // Handle success
    });
});
```

And the lifecycle callback in the Order model:

```
beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
    delete(values.line_items);
    cb();
}
```

But you really should look into bluebird promises as the model methods in version one of sails have opt in support for them and it helps to negate the pyramid of doom that is starting in my example and is also something that you want to avoid :P

Comment: The "key-value pairs sent by the webhook" means that shopify sends me a json object that is over 100 items long. If I wanted to just store everything as a json object, I could just use mongodb, but I need to perform relational queries, like a count of how many of each product was sold in a given date range.

Comment: @hamncheez Then what you have done sounds quite sane, if you're having trouble with too much code for processing the data then do look into Services, build one that has methods for all of the logic required within that part. Seem's to me that you might only need to do this once, then it's done and you can use the functionality?

Comment: @hamncheez Check my edit at the end of my answer, that should make it more manageable?

Comment: Services seems to be a great solution to keep my controller short, but I'm still not sure how to save to the two tables correctly.

Comment: @hamncheez my code was bad, revised it again, think it's right now so you have the `newOrder` variable containing all the data for the order and `newLine_items` will contain all the line items for the order. You can use the the ORM to deal with your data after that: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models

Comment: @hamncheez Thinking about it, you need only that `newOrders` variable. You can pass that into the order models create method but make a beforeCreate callback that removes any data that doesnt belong in the model (http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) and in your case it is `newOrders.line_items` as you're storing this data in a different model. Then, you will pass `newOrders.line_items` into the create method of your line items model. Keep it simple ;)

Comment: @hamncheez Gave you another example on how the flow of the logic might work here but realized that you actually need the order id as part of the newLine_items so that you can store the data associated to the order.

Comment: won't that create all the line items in an order as an array in a single record? That would make queries on the line_items table a bit hard. Would it be bad to do line_items.create() in a ._forEach loop, so each line_item is its own record in the table?

Comment: @hamncheez `var newLine_items = []` It was supposed to be an array, edited the answer, my bad. But the model methods create and update accept an object or an array of objects, so no. With the variable as an array of objects then it will create multiple records in your table. Yes your idea is bad because it is not how the model methods are supposed to be used and it would likely be less efficient. They accept one or many as a fundamental so use the many option where it applies by preprocessing the data going into it.

Comment: @hamncheez I'm not sure of which order id is being used, if you use the id from the web hook maybe as the id in your table then my previous edit is correct but if not, you need to add the id of the order that was created as the `order_id` of the line items, so i adjusted my example to account for this.

Comment: thanks for the help; it all works IF I don't use the beforeCreate()  method in the model and I remove the data in the controller; when its in the model it throw this weird error with no specifics: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error\n    at new WLError

Comment: @Glad to have helped. You can take a look at the sails Documentation for lifecycle callbacks in the ORM if you'd like to get beforeCreate to work. Not sure what I might have done wrong as it seems according to the docs. But hey, it work's so no problems there, good luck with your reporting application, sounds cool ;)